# Media query div background image change weirdness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have div with a simple background image. I'd need to change the image and how it's being displayed for responsiveness however I see some weird behavior happening when I resize the browser, the cover image either doesn't show at first or shows in pieces, when I resize a second time even if it's just one pixel change it starts showing. Refreshing the browser in any size works just fine. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
.mydiv {
  background: url(../img/background1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .mydiv {
    background: url(../img/background2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Edit: I've noticed that when I inspect element and touch .mydiv the weirdness goes away, so I wonder if there's a way to get Javascript or JQuery to refresh my element or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of things right off the bat:

1. Add a space between `@media` and `(max-width:992px)`
2. Are you using a `mydiv` element, or is that supposed to be a class or ID name? If it's a class or id, then you need to refer to it as either `.mydiv` (class) or `#mydiv` (ID) in your CSS.

[Here's a working jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/vrgkqsjb/)

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's a class and the space is there. I just typed it wrong here. Interestingly enough when I go from lower widths to higher, everything looks just fine, only when I go from higher pixels to lower or when the background needs to be a cover is when the weirdness happens. I need to pause and resize again to see the background show up correctly!

Comment: @user3376065 are you seeing that same behavior in my jsfiddle? I'm not seeing that on my end.

Comment: No yours is smooth in my browser, then there must be something else at play here.

Comment: @user3376065 I'm assuming that there is more code that what I'm seeing in your post. Is there any other related styling or markup that you can include? Or perhaps try adding it to my code slowly until you find the culprit?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the media query correctly, adding a space and if you wish for more clarity use @media which by itself it's impliciting defining @media all, but you can also use a parameter but then you need to add

*I'm using 768px just for testing purposes in this case. Update it with the value you need.*

```
      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      }
```

**DEMO CODE**

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
.mydiv {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1000x1000/FFF/000') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .mydiv {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1000x1000/) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
  }
}
```

Check this demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/v575uvyb/5/

Comment: I tried better writing my media query and including screen, it did not help. I noticed that by inspecting element and simply touching .mydiv everything gets fixed and the funkiness disappears! I'm updating my question whit this and I wonder if there's a way to use Javascript or jQuery to refresh an element.

Comment: Sure, I suggest you to write a new question. :)